# Go to specific page content in Joomla

Tags: html, joomla, module

Hi guys i have a question,
Im currently working on a Joomla site, but i cant get a "Go to `#News`" working.
Because there is no `<DIV> <ID>` used in Joomla Modules.
I have tried the ID of the Joomla module, but it wont work either.
I did a lot of Googling but i cant find any solution for this based on Joomla.
My Joomla site is HTML5 so i had the feeling this would work.
I hope that anyone can answer this question.

How it must work: Module 1 needs an link that goes to Module 2 on the same page. (They are both showing on the homepage)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I will confess I don't know what it is you're trying to achieve... as "Go to #News" doesn't ring any bells for me.

But, one can always override the output of any Joomla module with a procedure documented at: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

You could then add any div (s) you like.